# Ember Router and Controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I try to get the [example](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) from the Ember Guide to work but I dont get it:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map ->
  this.route("about");
  this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" })

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set('title', "My App")
});
```

Template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
  {{#linkTo "index"}}Index{{/linkTo}}
  {{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}
  {{#linkTo "favorites"}}Favorites{{/linkTo}}
</nav>
```

As I understand the example it should display the title when I reach the index page, but nothing happens. So could some see whats wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `title` property in the `IndexController`, but it seems like your template is not the `index` template but rather the `application` template. You can change your `IndexRoute` to use [`controllerFor`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_controllerFor) so you can access the `ApplicationController` (auto generated) and set a value to the property, similar to this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    @controllerFor('application').set('title', 'My App')
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/6fWhJ/))

Or you can do it directly in the `ApplicationRoute`:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('title', 'My App')
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/f8X3E/))

Answer (score 0):

Ok the this small sentence seems to be important here:

> The IndexController is the starting context for the index template

So the `{{title}}` has to be in the index template:

```
script(type="text/x-handlebars")

    <nav>
    {{#linkTo "index"}}Index{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo "favorites"}}Favorites{{/linkTo}}
    </nav>
    {{outlet}}

script(type="text/x-handlebars", data-template-name="index")
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
```